# Excel: compare two columns in two different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am stuck for comparison of two columns in two different sheets of Excel. I used different ways and formula but they don't work.

In *Sheet1* in `column L` I have *Date* by format of e.g 1/19/2012 and `column M` is *"Time"* by format of (e.g 19:00).

[image: sheet1]

In *Sheet2* `column B` is *Date* with the same format of *Sheet1*, and `column C` is *"Time"* with the same format of *Sheet1*.

[image: sheet2]

I want to compare **date and time** of two sheets and check if they are matched then bring the appropriate value from *Sheet2* `column D` to a new `column O` in *Sheet1* .

I used the formula `=L2 & "-" & M2` in *Sheet 1* in `column N` to have a merged column and used `=B2 & "-" & C2` in *Sheet2* in `column A` to have a merged column.

Now Im trying to compare *Sheet1* `Column N` and *Sheet2* `Column A` and see if they are matched then bring related value from *Sheet2* `Column D` to *Sheet1* `Column O` but it doesn't work.

**Note**: *Sheet1* has 1876 rows but *Sheet2* has 8785 rows.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or more data.  To compare 2 columns on one sheet with two columns on another sheet =if(and(sheet1!l1=sheet2!b1,sheet1!m1=sheet2!c1),"Matched","Did not Match")  is a prototype for a solution

Comment: here you can see a screenshot of two sheets. http://www.filedropper.com/newmicrosoftworddocument

Comment: I dont want to say matched or did not matched, i want to say if matched then bring the value from column D of sheet2 to column O in sheet1.

Comment: " but it doesn't work." - what you've tried, and how exactly it doesn't work (error message, wrong results. ..)?

Answer (score 1):

I have re-created your spreadsheet, with the exception of the "combined" column because it isn't necessary if you were only using it to be able to match.

From what I understood, you have 2 columns on sheet1 that you want to match against 2 columns on sheet2. If they do match, you want to copy a column from sheet2 back to sheet1. This can be done using 2 IF() statements within Excel. Note that this will only work for sequential rows. You mentioned sheet1 has 1876 rows but sheet2 has 8785 rows; this will only match on those first 1876 rows.

Here are the two worksheets I have setup. They are close to yours.

[image: Excel sheet 1] 
[image: Excel Sheet 2]

As you can see in the pictures, I have made rows 2 and 3 the same in each sheet, and then I made the date and time not match in row 4, and only the time not match in row 5.

If both items match, it takes the information from column C on sheet 2 and shows it in column C on sheet 1, which I believe is what you're asking for.

The IF formula in Excel looks like this: "IF(Test,[Value if True],[Value if False])". So what we do is first check if your dates match. If they do, then we use a second test to see if your times match. If either one fails, then we know they don't match.

Here is the formula in C2:

```
=IF(A2=Sheet2!A2,IF(B2=Sheet2!B2,Sheet2!C2,"Time doesn't match"),"Date doesn't match")
```

To break down the formula, it says:
IF A2 from sheet 1 equals A2 on sheet 2 [IF(A2=Sheet2!A2], then also check IF B2 on sheet one equals B2 on sheet 2 [IF(B2=Sheet2!B2]. If they do match then put the contents of C2 from sheet 2 in to B2 [Sheet2!C2]. If they don't match at this point then put "Time doesn't match" in B2. If the initial date test hadn't matched then put "Date doesn't match" in B2.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and consideration. I was useful.

Comment: If this answer was your solution, please mark it as the solution to help others know. (You and the answerer will also get rep points)